# Importing Excel spreadsheet data into another Excel spreadsheet - then move to next line

Tags: excel, vba, import

I am importing cells from a source spreadsheet to target spreadsheet.

Using the below code I browse for the source spreadsheet from the target and import the data.

[Importing Excel spreadsheet data into another Excel spreadsheet containing VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876178/importing-excel-spreadsheet-data-into-another-excel-spreadsheet-containing-vba)

My issue is importing the data to the next blank row on the target spreadsheet.

I have used this to add new row "ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown" when working on a single spreadsheet, but when I used it here it adds a line on the source spreadsheet (the one import data from).

I've tried this one too but can't get it to browse
https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-another-workbook/

I want to browse for excel spreadsheet and import it then when I repeat the process for different spreadsheet it will add to the next row.

```
Dim customerBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook filter = "Text files(.xlsx),.xlsx" 

caption = "Please Select an input file " 

customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet: Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet: Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 

targetSheet.Range("A1", "C10").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1", "C10").ValuecustomerWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: Where does this code reside?  In a Standard Module or in  Worksheet object?

Comment: Worksheet object, an "open" button

Comment: First thing you will want to do is identify the last row without data in the `targetSheet` by using `Dim lRow As Long` and then `lRow = targetSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count.End(xlUp).row` (update the "A" to whatever column the data is being moved to)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (You may need to adjust the ranges based on where you want the data to be passed to)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     Dim customerBook As Workbook, targetWorkbook As Workbook
     Dim filter As String, caption As String, customerFilename As String
     Dim lRow as Long

     Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook filter = "Text files(.xlsx),.xlsx" 

     caption = "Please Select an input file " 

     customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

     Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)

     Dim targetSheet As Worksheet: Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
     Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet: Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 

targetSheet.Range("A" & lRow).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1", "C10").Value 
customerWorkbook.Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately code above does not add the next imported data to the next row.

Comment: did you change the ranges to match where your data is coming from and where its going?

Comment: When I add in the line: "lRow = targetSheet.Range("A" & lRows).Count.End(xlUp).Row" I get error - "Compile error: Invalid qualifier" and highlights "Count"

When i remove the above line and leave 
"targetSheet.Range("A1" & lRow).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1").Value"
it add in the cells about 10 rows down from a1 but when i browse for second excel sheet it over rights the current rows. 

For my tests im only using column A with 5 cells of data (A1 to A5).